# UICollectionView is not reloading data properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I'm using a `UICollectionView` to display some data received from a remote server and I'm making two `reloadData` calls in a short time, first one to show a spinner (which is actually a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in a `UICollectionViewCell`) and the second one after the data was retrieved from server. I store the models based on which the collection view cells are created in a `self.models` NSArray and in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I dequeue cells based on this model. My issue is that when I call `reloadData` after the request was completed (the second time) the collection view seems to be still in the process of creating the cells for the first `reloadData` call and it shows just the first two cells and a big blank space in place where the rest of the cells should appear.

I wrote some logs to get some insights of what's happening and the current workflow is:

1. I'm populating `self.models` with the model for the spinner cell and then I call `reloadData` on the UICollectionView.
2. `numberOfItemsInSection` is called, which is just returning `[self.models count]`. The returned value is 2, which is fine (one cell which acts like a header + the second cell which is the one with the UIActivityIndicator inside).
3. I'm making the request to the server, I get the response and I populate `self.models` with the new models received from the remote server (removing the model for the spinner cell but keeping the header cell). I call `reloadData` on the UICollectionView instance.
4. `numberOfItemsInSection` is called, which is now returning the number of items retrieved from the remote server + the model for the header cell (let's say that the returned value is 21).
5. It's just now when `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is called but just twice (which is the value returned by `numberOfItemsInSection` when it was called first).

It seems like the collection view is busy with the first `reloadData` when I call this method for the second time. How should I tell the collection view to stop loading cells for the first `reloadData` call? I tried with `[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]` which seemed to work but the issue reappeared, so it didn't did the trick.

Some snippets from my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [ ...... ]

    self.models = @[];
    self.newsModels = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    [self buildModel:YES];  // to show the loading indicator
    [self.collectionView reloadData];

    [self updateNewsWithBlock:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
            [self buildModel:NO];
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        });
    }];
}

- (void) buildModel:(BOOL)showSpinnerCell {
    NSMutableArray *newModels = [NSMutableArray array];
    [newModels addObject:self.showModel];  // self.showModel is the model for the cell which acts as a header
    if ([self.newsModels count] != 0) {
        // self.newsModels is populated in [self updateNewsWithBlock], see below
        [newModels addObjectsFromArray:self.newsModels];
    } else if (showSpinnerCell) {
        [newModels addObject:[SpinnerCellModel new]];
    }

    self.models = [NSArray arrayWithArray:newModels];
}

- (void) updateNewsWithBlock:(void (^)())block {
    // Here I'm performing a GET request using `AFHTTPSessionManager` to retrieve
    // some XML data from a backend, then I'm processing it and
    // I'm instantiating some NewsCellModel objects which represents the models.
   [ ..... ]

   for (NSDictionary *item in (NSArray*)responseObject) {
       NewsCellModel *model = [[NewsCellModel alloc] init];
       model.itemId = [item[@"id"] integerValue];
       model.title = item[@"title"];
       model.headline = item[@"short_text"];
       model.content = item[@"text"];
       [self.newsModels addObject:model];
   }

   block();
}
```

Comment: Please post your code. Especially the parts where you call the 'reloadData' method.

Comment: Are you calling the `reloadData` in main thread?

Comment: also, are you calling reloadData after settings self.models?

Comment: Larme - yes, I'm calling `reloadData` in the main thread.

Comment: marosoaie - yes, for now every time I'm wanting to reload data I'm calling `[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];`, then `[self buildModel]` which is a method where the `self.models` array is built then I call `[self.collectionView reloadData];`

Comment: You call the `block();` after the `for (NSDictionary *item in (NSArray*)responseObject)` is not done INSIDE inside the successBlock of the AFNetworking method?

Comment: Larme - yes, the block(); is called inside the success block of the `AFNetworking` method, right after the for loop.

Comment: show full code of updateNewsWithBlock. I don't see, that block() called in success block.